# vector size reverts to 0 outside constructor

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

I have a class [Network] that during construction creates a vector of objects [Nodes]

inside the constructor I have the declaration

```
vector<Node> Nodes (NodeCount);
```

where NodeCount is an int, lets say 5

inside the constructor I can call

```
cout << Nodes.size()
```

and the output will be 5

here is the constructor

```
Network::Network()

//establish initial Node count for network
/*
cout << "How many Nodes: ";
cin >> NodeCount;
*/

NodeCount = 5;
vector<Node> Nodes (NodeCount);
cout << "Nodes.size(): " << Nodes.size() << endl;

//initialize tables for all Nodes
for(int i = 0; i < Nodes.size(); i++)
{
    Nodes[i].initTable(i, NodeCount);
    //cout << "Nodes[" << i << "].table[0] - " << Nodes[i].table[0] << endl;


debug();
```

- pardon the comments i was trying to debug

but outside the constructor if I am in say this function

```
void Network::debug()

cout << "NodeCount: " << NodeCount << endl;
cout << "Nodes.size(): " << getSize() << endl;
```

this is the output

```
NodeCount: 5
Nodes.size(): 0
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that within the constructor you defined local variable

```
vector<Node> Nodes (NodeCount);
```

that after exiting the constructor is destroyed.

You have to use the corresponding data member of the class instead of this local variable.

Comment: @BKreger Any programmer can make an error that is evident for others.:)